# Chaquopy: Convert Java ArrayList/LinkedList to Python Array

Tags: java, python, android, chaquopy

Good evening guys,

yesterday I found out that we can use [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) to run Python scripts from Java. I have played around with it a little bit and came across the following problem:

`ArrayList`-Objects (resp. `LinkedList`-Objects), which I have passed to a Python script, do not behave as I would expect it. In Python, I can't just use `list[index]` with an `ArrayList`, that comes from Java. The following exception is thrown:

> com.chaquo.python.PyException: TypeError: 'LinkedList' object is not subscriptable

I have looked at the Chaquopy-Documentation and couldn't find any information about Java-List support. Only arrays are stated there.

Now my question:
Do I have to convert all my lists to arrays in Java before passing them to Python?

Thank you all

Comment: Probably convert any LinkedList objects to ArrayList. Just speculating.

Comment: First of fall, thank you for your response. Sadly, that's not working. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough: the problem occurs in both cases, linkedlists as well as arraylists. I will add a code example to my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, Chaquopy supports accessing Java arrays using Python syntax, but not Java Lists. You can either:

- Copy the List to an array using [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#toArray()), and pass that to Python; or
- Pass the List to Python and have the Python code call its methods directly (i.e.[`size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#size()), [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)), etc.).

Comment: Meanwhile, I figured that out by myself, but anyways thanks for that clarification.

Comment: Maybe you could answer me one additional question: is it somehow possible to cast PyObjects that contain Python matrices to Java Lists/Arrays in Java without iterating through each element? What’s the best practice here?

Comment: Any iterable Python object can be converted to a compatible Java array type using `toJava`. But if the object implements the buffer protocol, and the Java array is of the matching type, then the conversion will be more efficient. For example, if your object is a NumPy `int16` array, then `toJava(short[].class)` will be very fast, while `toJava(int[].class)` will also work, but much more slowly.